# Enable logio Module in Ubuntu Apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04

How can I enable the logio module in Apache 2.2, Ubuntu 16.04?

In folder /etc/apache2/modules-available, I looked for something like logio.load and logio.conf but I did not find these.

When I query `apachectl -l`, I get:

```
Compiled in modules:
core.c
mod_so.c
mod_watchdog.c
http_core.c
mod_log_config.c
mod_logio.c
mod_version.c
mod_unixd.c
```

I installed apache through `apt-get install apache2` (I did not build the server from binaries), and as you can read above mod_logio.c was a compiled-in module.

Can I enable logio given the set up I describe?

Is it possible to get logio.load and logio.conf from some repository (I see this files pattern for other modules at my server's /etc/apache2/modules-available)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to enable it.

Modules can either be loaded at compile time or dynamically in the config using the `LoadModule` directive. Enabling a module using `a2enmod` simply adds a `LoadModule` directive in `mods-enabled` directory, which in turn is included by the following lines in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf
```

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/configuring.html#modules

> httpd is a modular server. This implies that only the most basic functionality is included in the core server. Extended features are available through modules which can be loaded into httpd. **By default, a base set of modules is included in the server at compile-time. If the server is compiled to use dynamically loaded modules, then modules can be compiled separately and added at any time using the LoadModule directive.** Otherwise, httpd must be recompiled to add or remove modules. Configuration directives may be included conditional on a presence of a particular module by enclosing them in an  block. However,  blocks are not required, and in some cases may mask the fact that you're missing an important module.
>
> To see which modules are currently compiled into the server, you can use the -l command line option. You can also see what modules are loaded dynamically using the -M command line option.